# Symfony Access DB over HTTP login/password

Tags: symfony, http, doctrine

Can someone tell me if it's possible to connect to a remote database that have a http login/password protection. I setted the database parameters in parameters.yml but he  can't connect due to the login/password authentication. Maybe i have to do something before doing queries ? Or put something in addition in the parameters like database_http_login and database_http_password. I don't think this exists but de never know !

Thanks everybody !!

Comment: mysql wouldn't use http authentication - perhaps the problem is that the database port is not exposed to your remote IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the parameters in you paramaters file

```
database_host: REMOTEIPORNAME
database_port: 3306
database_name: NAME
database_user: USER
database_password: PASSWORD
```

if this doesn't work, you user is propably not allowed to remote access.
You can try that on a linux or mac machine with `mysql --host=REMOTEIPORNAME -u USER NAME --password=PASSWORD`. If this works you connection is fine. 
Otherwise you have to edit the privileges on the host database with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename . * TO 'database_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hope that helps